# PHP date within 6 months

Tags: php, date, comparison

How I can check if given date (ie. 4/2017) is within 6 months from now in future?

For example:

```
4/2017 true
8/2017 false
5/2017 true
```

I have now:

```
$datum = explode(': ', $given_date); // Separate date from string
$datum = str_replace('/', '-', $datum[1]); // Given format month/year
$datum = strtotime('01-'.$datum); // Given only month/year
$limit_datum = strtotime('+6 months');
```

But I'm tilted right now, and can't get how to compare it...

Comment: Use [`DateTime`](https://secure.php.net/DateTime).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using DateTime, it becomes very trivial:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$input = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/Y', '4/2017');

$diff = $input->diff($now); // Returns DateInterval

// m is months
$lessThanSixMonths = $diff->y === 0 && $diff->m < 6;  // true
```

See [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) and [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

Comment: This works, however I had to do some fixes to check if there is really date given, if its empty or in wrong format, diff returns fatal error. However after fixes this works.

Comment: @Diamonte Yes, of course, you still have to validate your user input!

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this

```
$todayDate = time();
$date_6_months = strtotime("+6 months");
$givenDate = strtotime($date);
if ($givenDate > $todayDate && $givenDate < $date_6_months){
     put your code
}
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:I change my previous wrong script.In this one you can compare strings of two dates

```
    $given_date= "...."; //set given date (m/Y)
    $current_date = date("m/Y",mktime());

    $month_given  = strtok($given_date, '/');
    $year_given = strtok('/');
    $month_now  = strtok($current_date, '/');
    $year_now = strtok('/');

    $diff_year = $year_given - $year_now;
    $diff_month = $month_given - $month_now;
    $our_diff = $diff_year * 12 + $diff_month;

    if($our_diff <= 6 && $our_diff >= 0){
      //less or equal than 6months
    }
    else if($our_diff > 6){
     //more than sixmonths
    }
    else{
    //negative number
    }
```

Comment: Subtracting two strings in `m/Y` format will yield nonsensical results.

Comment: you were right i change my script with another method. Danke